# AEM - Help to create the site in adobe documentation

Tags: aem

I am new to Adobe AEM and currently I'm going through the documentation - **How to Create a Fully Featured Internet Website**. I'm using AEM 6.1.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/the-basics/website.html

I'm following the steps under *Using the Foundation Page Scripts* in ENHANCING THE CONTENTPAGE SCRIPT. I'm supposed to get the sidekick if I hit the following URL but I don't.

http://localhost:4502/content/mywebsite/en/products.html

The interesting thing is if I use the following url,I get the sidekick. http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/mywebsite/en/products.html

Could anyone tell me why I'm not getting sidekick though I follow the steps mentioned in the documentation.Am I missing something?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In AEM 6.1, by default, pages in siteadmin are designed to open in touch UI where you'll find editor.html in the URL. To switch to classic UI you will have to replace editor.html to cf# which is when CQ understands to invoke init.js which renders the sidekick.

Answer (score 0):

The URL http://localhost:4502/content/mywebsite/en/products.html you are expecting to get the sidekick with, is the preview mode of the page or what end user will see.
Modes in which you will get sidekick to edit your page will contain **cf#** or **editor.html** after the domain name which is called **classic view** and **Touch UI** in AEM

To edit page in **Classic mode** : http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/mywebsite/en/products.html

To edit page in **Touch UI** :
Replace **cf#** with **editor.html**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Classic UI on regular basis, you can change the user preferences to use Classic UI.

It is highly advised to Touch UI as AEM is moving away from Classic.

Reference : https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/author-environment/user-properties.html#User%20Preferences